# Are there any free Hadith texts available online in the original Arabic?

Tags: hadith, reference-request, books

I am looking for *text* format (i.e. not PDF) of the various Hadiths online somewhere for free download. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: There are plenty of onlinrle resources such as sunnah.com, Islamweb , etc. A simple online-research would easily answer this.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum, 
There is a website called ahadith.com. i suggest u try that as it has daily hadith and hadith and duas in general.